# I need to use Prototype to do something I can easily do in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I know my jQuery, but sadly don't know much about Prototype.

```
$(function() {
     $('#home-gallery-container').append('<a href="/images/cobra_sale.jpg" alt="" rel="lightbox-home" id="special-home" ><img src="/images/tag.png" alt="Special" /></a>');
});
```

How would I do this in Prototype, or Magento's library if that adds anything extra.

Note in the sample above, I *have* taken into account `jQuery.noConflict()` etc

Comment: everything is easy when you know how :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('home-gallery-container').insert({
    bottom:'<a href="/images/cobra_sale.jpg" alt="" rel="lightbox-home" id="special-home" ><img src="/images/tag.png" alt="Special" /></a>'
});
```

See [Element.Insert in Prototype's Docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#insert-class_method).

Comment: FYI `insert()` defaults to `"bottom"` if just passed the html string directly.

Comment: @Crescent: Thanks. I often forget what it default to and so I tend to explicitly state what I want where.